# Boot problems with HP compaq 8100

Tags: boot, bios, desktop-computer

When I plug my PC into the power outlet and press the power button, only the (HDD?) light turns on and when I let go of the button, it turns off.

But if I reset the CMOS (BIOS), it boots, goes through whole "Hardware changed" and "Time not set", it boots perfectly. I also replaced the BIOS battery, so if that was the problem, it no longer is. Once I pull it out of the outlet and plug it back in, the problem occurs once again.

I've run memtest86+ and checked the HDD for defects, but no success.
I tried changing BIOS settings and disabled security stuff, as that could have been causing it, but no luck.

Any more suggestions or further insight into the problem?

If you need more context, I can post pictures if needed.

Comment: There's likely a hardware issue somewhere, as that sounds like the protection mechanism that exists to prevent hardware damage if POST determines there's a critical hardware issue somewhere that could cause electrical damage to the system.  Try unplugging & re-seating all connectors/hardware (w/ power switched off/unplugged from outlet), restore power, then power back on. You can try clearing the BIOS memory if it still doesn't boot, but unless you're 100% sure it's not a hardware issue, doing so could result in the system booting w/ the hardware issue still there and cause electrical damage.

Comment: Oh, so that protection blocks the startup every time the PC is started? It's weird, because if I just power it off and turn it back on again, it works flawlessly, but if I unplug it, the problem appears.

Comment: _"...if I just power it off and turn it back on again..."_ Via the OS, or the power button on the 8100?

Comment: Either. The problem only occurs when it's fully plugged out of the wall. Ok, windows complains when I turn it off with the power button, but that shouldn't matter in this case. I also just reseated cables and the issue still persists. As I'm going to be using it for home-use, could I disable that BIOS "feature"?

Comment: It's not POST's protection feature then.  Does it only occur the first time you turn it on after unplugging/plugging it in, or will it continue to do so?  If it's the latter, I'm not sure what would be causing that.

Comment: Whenever I plug it back into the outlet, no matter what I do, whenever I press the button the HDD led lights up, until I let go. No fans can be heard, so they're probably not spinning. Only after I clear the CMOS, I can finally boot the system.

Comment: I have no idea then, as that's exactly like what POST's protection action looks like.  Have you booted into hardware diagnostics and ran a full test (it takes several hours to complete)?

Comment: I haven't run anything besides memtest86+ and their HDD tester. I'll do that now and will see where that gets us, thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @JW0914 sorry for the misinformation. If I force-power off the computer, the same error occurs. but if I just press it, once booted, it turns off fine.